# $G$ is a group. $G$ contain element $a$, prove $a^n*a^{-n}=e$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am a beginner for abstract algebra.
I have tried to solve this problem.Could anyone helps me to check
I have given a reason near each step.[these are my steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4wd2.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You're supposed to use Latex to write your questions on this site. At least having an image with the right orientation would be friendly to your readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by induction. We have
$$ a^{n+1} \cdot (a^{-1})^{n+1} = a^n\cdot a \cdot a^{-1} \cdot (a^{-1})^n = a^n \cdot e \cdot (a^{-1})^n = a^n \cdot (a^{-1})^n$$
Therefore, if $a^n \cdot (a^{-1})^n = e$, then $ a^{n+1} \cdot (a^{-1})^{n+1} = e$. Since for $n=1$ we have $$a^1 \cdot a^{-1} = a \cdot a^{-1} = e$$ by induction it means that $a^n \cdot (a^{-1})^n = e$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks.A theorem that any two

Comment: Thanks. A theorem that

Comment: By A theorem that any two ways to multiply elements of group G produce same element in G, a^n and a^(-n) are in G, a in G multiplies itself n times still in G, a^(-1) in G multiplies itself n times still in G, according to this theorem again, a^n*e*a^(-n)=(a^n*a^(-n))*e,if first bracket inside is e,e*e=e

Comment: Is what I think correct ?

Comment: You blew my cover!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Show that if two elements $\;a,b\;$ in **any group** $\;G\;$ *commute* (meaning that $\;ab=ba\;$) , then $\;(ab)^n=a^nb^n\;$ for all $\;n\in\Bbb Z\;$

Answer (score 1):

A method that does not require a commutative property:

By definitions:

$a\cdot a^{-1}=e$

$a^{k+1}=(a^k)\cdot a$

$a^{-(k+1)}=(a^{-k})\cdot a^{-1}$ which also $=(a^{-1})\cdot a^{-k}$ by associativity

Now use associativity and mathematical induction to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to consider the power laws in groups.

Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$.

(1) Define $a^0 =e $ (unit element) and $a^{n+1} = a\cdot a^n$ for each integer $n\geq 0$. It is clear that $a^1=a$, since $a^1 = a\cdot a^0 = a\cdot e = a$.

(2) For each integer $n\geq 0$, define $a^{-n} = (a^{-1})^n$. This gives you the definition of negative powers.

(3) For all integers $m,n$, we obtain $a^m\cdot a^n = a^{m+n}$.

This gives you the solution of your problem by (3) and (1):

$a^n\cdot a^{-n} = a^{n+(-n)} = a^0=e.$

Commutativity is not necessary here.

Comment: Commutativity is implictly used in $\;a^n\cdot a^{-n}=a^{n-n}...\;$